# Proving a relation is transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I am trying to understand transitive relations.

I understand given that a set may have $\{(a,b)(b,c)\}$ it must contain $(a,c)$ for it to be transitive.

But for longer sets I am getting confused in finding out if it is transitive.

So if I had a set: $\{(1,1)(1,3)(1,5)(2,2)(2,4)(3,1)(3,3)(3,5)(4,2)(4,4)(5,1)(5,3)(5,5)\}$

For example: I have $\{(1,3)\}$ and $\{(3,5)\}$ which means I need $\{(1,5)\}$ which I do.

But to prove it is transitive would I need $\{(1,1)\}$ having $\{(1,3)(3,1)\}$?

Also how many transitive relations are within that set?

Comment: You are talking about a transitive *relation*, not about a [transitive *set*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set), which is a different technical concept. Please edit accordingly, to avoid confusion.

Comment: To answer your particular question: Yes, transitivity plus symmetry of a relation implies reflexivity. So you would need `(1, 1)` if you had `(1, 3), (3, 1)` (you would also need `(3, 3)`, just so you know). In the case of a list of ordered pairs like yours, you actually have to check every single pair of pairs, see if they make a "demand" of transitivity (i.e. one of them ends with the same number the other begins with), and check whether that demanded pair is actually an element of the relation. If your relation is rather given as a general description, that'd take a different strategy.

Comment: would that be `(3,3)` in my example? or the `{(1,3)(3,1)}` example, or both?

Comment: @JohnAnderson That would be `(3, 3)` in the `{(1, 3),(3, 1)}`-example. Because you can read it the "other way", that is `{(3, 1), (1, 3)}`, so you need `(3, 3)` as well. In your big example, you just have to check that for _every_ pair of pairs `(a, b), (b, c)` you also have `(a, c)`. You have `(1, 3), (3, 5)` therefore you need `(1, 5)` and so on.

Comment: For a specific, not too large example, like the one you give, it can be helpful to draw a diagram: represent the elements as dots, and the ordered pairs as arrows between the dots. (Look up _directed graph_.) Transitivity says that whenever you have an arrow from A to B and from B to C, you must also have one from A to C.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a nice theorem which helps in determining whether or not a relation is transitive. Let's define a relation $\mathbf{R}$ on a set $A$. We know that this defines a relation $\mathbf{R}:A \longrightarrow A$. Now, we want to prove that $\mathbf{R}$ is a transitive relation.

Theorem: $\mathbf{R}$ is a transitive relation if and only if $\mathbf{R}^{n} \subseteq \mathbf{R}$ for every positive integer $n$.

$\mathbf{Proof} (\longrightarrow)$:(via mathematical induction)

Suppose $\mathbf{R}$ is a transitive relation. Define the propositional function $P(n)$ such that $P(n)$ implies that $\mathbf{R}^{n} \subseteq \mathbf{R}$. Now we check the base case: $n=1$. Since $\mathbf{R}^{1}=\mathbf{R}$, it follows that $\mathbf{R}^{1} \subseteq \mathbf{R}$ and so $P(1)$ is true. We now must show that if $P(n)$ is true, then $P(n+1)$ is true. In other words, if $\mathbf{R}^{n} \subseteq \mathbf{R}$ then $\mathbf{R}^{n+1} \subseteq \mathbf{R}$. Let $\alpha,\beta \in A$ such that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are related under $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$. More compactly, we may write this as $(\alpha, \beta) \in \mathbf{R}^{n+1}$. Recall that $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$ is the composition of $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ and $\mathbf{R}$; in other words: $\mathbf{R}^{n+1} = \mathbf{R}^{n} \circ \mathbf{R}$. Now, since $(\alpha,\beta) \in \mathbf{R}^{n+1}$, it follows from the definition of a transitive relation that there exists $\theta \in A$ such that $(\alpha,\theta) \in \mathbf{R}$ and $(\theta, \beta) \in \mathbf{R}^{n}$. Since $\mathbf{R}^{n} \subseteq \mathbf{R}$, we know that $(\theta, \beta) \in \mathbf{R}$. Since we defined $\mathbf{R}$ as a transitive relation, it follows that $(\alpha ,\beta) \in \mathbf{R}$. Therefore $\mathbf{R}^{n+1} \subseteq \mathbf{R}$.

$\mathbf{Proof} (\longleftarrow)$:

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbf{R}$ such that $(a,b) \in \mathbf{R}$ and $(b,c) \in \mathbf{R}$. Now can compose $\mathbf{R}$ with itself; in other words, take $\mathbf{R} \circ \mathbf{R}$. If we do so, then $(a,c) \in \mathbf{R} \circ \mathbf{R} = \mathbf{R}^{2}$. By hypothesis,$\mathbf{R}^{2} \subseteq \mathbf{R}$, and thus $(a,c) \in \mathbf{R}$. Therefore $\mathbf{R}$ is transitive.

This completes the proof.

Now you have posed a very insightful question regarding the number of transitive relations on a set. Until now, the only way to compute the number of transitive relations is to find them via brute-force methodology: counting transitive relations is an open problem in combinatorics!

Hope this helped.

Comment: +1 for "counting transitive relations is an open problem in combinatorics."

Comment: https://youtu.be/L3LMbpZIKhQ?t=2244 In this link, the professor mentions `if a = b, and b = c, then a = c` and then goes on to say that **there is no proof for this**. So there is no way to prove transitive property for any relation?